# Using Wordpress LOOP with pages instead of posts?

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way to use **THE LOOP** in **Wordpress** to load pages instead of posts?

I would like to be able to query a set of child pages, and then use **THE LOOP** function calls on it - things like `the_permalink()` and `the_title()`.

Is there a way to do this? I didn't see anything in `query_posts()` documentation.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Yes, that's possible. You can create a new WP_Query object. Do something like this:

```
query_posts(array('showposts' => <number_of_pages_to_show>, 'post_parent' => <ID of the parent page>, 'post_type' => 'page'));

while (have_posts()) { the_post();
    /* Do whatever you want to do for every page... */
}

wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data
```

**Addition**: There are a lot of other parameters that can be used with query_posts. Some, but unfortunately not all, are listed here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/query_posts. At least `post_parent` and more important *`post_type`* are not listed there. I dug through the sources of `./wp-include/query.php` to find out about these.

Comment: If it's child pages of the current page you can use `get_the_ID()` if you've previously called `the_post()`.

Answer (score 22):

Given the age of this question I wanted to provide an updated answer for anyone who stumbles upon it.

I would suggest avoiding query_posts. Here's the alternative I prefer:

```
$child_pages = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'      => 'page', // set the post type to page
    'posts_per_page' => 10, // number of posts (pages) to show
    'post_parent'    => <ID of the parent page>, // enter the post ID of the parent page
    'no_found_rows'  => true, // no pagination necessary so improve efficiency of loop
) );

if ( $child_pages->have_posts() ) : while ( $child_pages->have_posts() ) : $child_pages->the_post();
    // Do whatever you want to do for every page. the_title(), the_permalink(), etc...
endwhile; endif;  

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Another alternative would be to use the pre_get_posts filter however this only applies in this case if you need to modify the primary loop. The above example is better when used as a secondary loop.

Further reading: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query